# Launch laravel on webserver with multiple sites and only one ip-address and one port

Tags: php, laravel, webserver, apache2

I have a laravel project and want to launch it on a webserver.

In xampp\htdocs are a lot of little scripts, projects and one laravel project.

How can I use these with only one ip-address?

If I want to access my old project I type: 192.168.178.120/projectXYZ

And I want to access the laravel project like: 192.168.178.120/laravelproject

I have only 1 IP-Address available for the webserver.

Normally I add a new local ip or use a different port than 80.

But I cannot get a new IP and other ports than 443 and 80 are blocked.

I hope someone know what I want to do :D

Comment: Do you use WIndows?

Comment: Yes, XAMPP is only available for windows

Comment: I would suggest using multiple virtual hosts with apache, if you have a registered domain name, then you can create as many subdomains as you want.

Comment: Good, just edit this file \WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and add necessary hosts

Comment: I know how to add new dns entrys, add new ports or create subdomains. But this is not what I want #

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1.**
Create a new folder in "htdocs\laravel", but you need to create a redirect to your public folder in your laravel (not secure because you expose whole framework to public)

**Method 2.**
Create a folder outside of htdocs like under "C:\Xampp\laravel\", then put all content inside public in" htdocs\laravel", then modify "index.php" to:

```
require "C:\xampp\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php";
$app = require_once "C:\xampp\laravel\bootstrap\app.php"; 
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```